# Adding percentage symbol to all x axis list's elements

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I use matplotlib and numpy.(*)

I have a list like this : [20,40,40]

When I plot a bar my x axis is naturally represents the list.But I want it to be like this : [20%,30%,40%] (represents the percentage value of list element's.) Is there any shortcut for this in these libraries (*) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`plt.xticks`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) to set the xticks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [1,2,3]
x = [20,30,40]

plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
plt.bar(x,y, align="center")
plt.xticks(x,["20%", "30%","40%"])

plt.show()
```

[image]